# What are the distributions of negative and positive parts of a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random

For a given random variable $X$, we define $X^+=\max\{0,X\}$ and $X^-=\max\{0,-X\}$.

My question is how to express the probabilities of the two R.V $X^+$ and $X^-$.

If we write: 
\begin{equation}
F_{X^+}(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(X \leq x; X\geq 0) =\mathbb{P}(X \leq x).\mathbb{P}(X\geq 0)
\end{equation}
And deduce: 
\begin{equation}
F_{X^+}(x)=  F_X(x).(1-F_X(0))
\end{equation}
and the same thing goes with $X^-$:
\begin{equation}
F_{X^-}(x)=  F_X(0).(1-F_X(x))
\end{equation}
is it right? Particularly, in this case neither $F_{X^+}$ nor $F_{X^-}$ equals to 1 when $x \rightarrow +\infty$. 
Please, if you have any suggestions, I am all ears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The events $\{X \le x\}$ and $\{X \ge 0\}$ are in general not independent, so you can't factor the CDF in this way.

Instead, remember that $\max(a, b) \le c$ is equivalent to $a \le c$ and $b \le c$. This yields:
$$P(X^+ \le x) = P(\max(0, X) \le x) = P(X \le x, 0 \le x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
P(X \le x) & x \ge 0
\end{cases}.$$

Similar calculations using $\min(a, b) > c \iff (a > c) \wedge (b > c)$ yield the CDF of $X^-$.

Comment: Can you please tell me if Bayes rule could help in this case to get a simplified formula?

Comment: I don't see how Bayes could be used here. This is a pretty simple form.

Comment: But I need to find the CDF or PDF form.

Comment: Differentiate, for pdf form.

Comment: This is the CDF form.